# SEO Canonical tag for multiple website

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, canonical-url

I have two websites following

```
website: abc.com having canocial tag abc.com  and i implemnted 301 redirect to abc.ca.

    abc.ca having canocial tag abc.ca
```

Problem is that when we  search  **abc on google,  abc.com is on top priority.**

**I want abc.ca on top priority.** 
Does canonical tag is causing issue ?Anybody suggest me what should i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need:

```
<link href="<original url>" rel="canonical">
```

if you're doing a 301 redirect because both are the same thing in terms of search engines trying to figure out which copy of your page is original.

Your best bet is to remove the link tag with canonical in it on your pages and implement a 301 redirect from the .com version of your site to the .ca version, so that when visitors visit the .com version, they will either be automatically be redirected (if they use a normal web browser), or they will land on a redirect page that indicates where the original page is located. On an apache server, the page will look something like this:

```
Moved

The document has been moved here.
```

and the word here is a link that directs users to the new original page when it is clicked.

Comment: i want when user search abc. i want abc.ca on top. currently abc.com is coming..

Comment: Google takes times to update its databases. After making changes, give google a week and see what happens.